# How to maintain a ftp connection using python's ftplib?

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a task queue. For each item, in the queue I am connecting to the ftp server and uploading the file.

Sample code that runs for each item in the task queue:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftpserverurl','username','password')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('bills')
with open(filename, 'rb') as f_read:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename, f_read)  
ftp.quit()
```

I want to improve this so the ftp connection is maintained and re-used for every file in the queue rather than establishing connection again for each file. Suppose I create the ftp connection in the global (top level of module) with following lines:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftpserverurl','username','password')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('bills')
```

Then for each item in the task queue, I can use the following lines:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f_read:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename, f_read)
```

No need to quit the connection because it needs to remain open to be able to service items from the task queue. There can be a situation where-in there are no items in the task queue for couple of hours and subsequently new items arrive in the queue, then will the ftplib connection remain open (not timeout) and allow ftp uploads? If not, then what is the approach to handle this situation?

Comment: Look into `keepalive` for FTP. The Python library you use may have such setting.

Comment: There is nothing called `keepalive` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html). There is timeout setting but I think that's a client timeout. The ftp server would have its own timeouts separately.

Comment: Ah, I see, then probably you need to do it manually by sending some no-op command (or ls probably) every some time period.